# How to run Qtcreator from terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, qt

Hi I have QtInstalled with the official qt installer (I haven't used the package with the name "qtcreator").

I need to run QtCreator from terminal but I can't locate the executable.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: if you have installed qtcreator  then run "qtcreator" command on terminal it should open qt.

Comment: @Arpit I used Qt Installer downloaded from their Website I didn't use the package installer with apt-get. QtCreator is a deprecated package....

Comment: @underscore_d I used Qt Installer downloaded from their Website I didn't use the package installer with apt-get. QtCreator is a deprecated package...

Comment: @C.Xammar Expected qt location will be:"/opt/qt-director name" move in that folder then run ./qtcreator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you can find the executable in opt directory the location will be as this /opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin and you can run it through terminal as ./qtcreator

Answer (score 5):

Latest QtCreator should by default be installed in

```
 ${HOME}/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/
```

And you have two start-up options, the executable `qtcreator` or the shell script `qtcreator.sh`

To run the executable, type

```
~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator
```

To run the shell script, type

```
~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.sh
```

Whic one to use: From the top portion of `qtcreator.sh`, it states that if you have library name conflicts (such as having same library names used by qtcreator with your own `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), you may want to start with the shell script, rather than the bare executable.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows linux subsystem users**

In case you have ubuntu as a subsystem for win10, it's located in your AppData folder (installing with sudo apt install command): 
Also, you cannot run qtcreator from terminal as graphical interface is not supported by defeault. You need to instal X-server app first (https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) and then you can run QT from terminal.

```
C:\Users\[YOUR_USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\usr\share\qtcreator
```

Or, it's in usr/lintian/overrides

**But you should not modify anything inside this linux root, as it may lead to data loss.**

Answer (score 0):

For me it wasn't in the `/opt` directory, but rather the location I've chosen in the `/home/user/` directory.
More specifically: `/home/user/Qt5.12.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator`